# Module not found while using the SVG file

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to use map_location in my project. I am stuck importing the svg file.

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Icons/3.svg' in 'C:\Users\WS035\Desktop\REACT JS\my_project\src\map_locations'

Thank you in advance.

Directories of my project is:

[image]

Map.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import L from 'leaflet';

import {
  MapContainer,
  TileLayer,
  Tooltip,
  Marker, 
  useMap,

} from "react-leaflet";

import TSFDICON from "./Icons/1.svg";
import TAISAICON from "./Icons/2.svg";
import BOTHICON from "./Icons/3.svg";

import "./Map.css";

const myIconTSFD = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: TSFDICON,
  popupAnchor: [-0, -0],
  iconSize: [40, 40],
});

const myIconTAISA = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: TAISAICON,
  popupAnchor: [-0, -0],
  iconSize: [40, 40],
});

const myIconBOTH = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: BOTHICON,
  popupAnchor: [-0, -0],
  iconSize: [40, 40],
});


function Legend() {
  const map = useMap();
  const position = "bottomleft";

 // Define the desired height and width (in pixels)
 const legendHeight = "200px";
 const legendWidth = "190px";

 // Apply the height and width as inline styles
 const legendStyle = {
   height: legendHeight,
   width: legendWidth,
 };

  return (
    <div
      className={`leaflet-control leaflet-control-custom leaflet-${position}`}
      style={legendStyle} // Apply the styles here
      >
      <div className="leaflet-control-layers leaflet-control-layers-expanded">
        <div className="leaflet-control-layers-body">
          <div>
           
            <img src={TSFDICON} className="icon" />
            <span style={{ color: "TAGF" }}>1</span>
            <br></br>
            <img src={BOTHICON} className="icon icon-both"/>
            <span style={{ color: "TAGF" }}>2</span>
            <br></br>
            <img src={TAISAICON} className="icon" />
            <span style={{ color: "TAGF" }}>3</span>
            <br></br>            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Map() {  

  return (
    <>     
      { (
        <MapContainer          
          zoom={10}
          maxZoom={14}
          minZoom={5}
          scrollWheelZoom={true}         
        >
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
            integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
            crossOrigin=""
          />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://unpkg.com/react-leaflet-markercluster/dist/styles.min.css"
          />
          <TileLayer
            url="https://cyberjapandata.gsi.go.jp/xyz/std/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='<a href="https://maps.gsi.go.jp/development/ichiran.html" target="_blank">地理院タイル</a>'
          />         
          {}
          <Legend />                  
        </MapContainer>
      )}     
    </>
  );
}
export default Map;
```

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import Map from './map_locations/Map';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">       
      </header>     
      <Map />    
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Your `Map.js` and SVG files are located in separate folders, but in your `Map.js` you are referring to them in relative paths as `./Icons/...`. You might want to replace the single `.` (current path) with a double `..` (parent path). That is, go one level up, and find the `Icons` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know the main problem is importing wrong, But its important to put your images out of your map directory do this and After that you can try this

```
import Tname from "../Icons/1.svg"

import Tname from "../Icons/2.svg";

import Bname from "../Icons/3.svg";
```